# How do you create a button with a gradient for the background color in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a requirement to have a button filled with a gradient colour (red to green) & can't seem to find a way to do this.

I am able to draw a rectangle & do a gradient fill, however I need the buttons backcolor property to have the gradient fill rather than a rectangle on top of the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the rectangle with a gradient fill, and add the text for the button, then save it as a .jpg/.gif and use an ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the BackgroundImage property on System.Windows.Forms.Button.
You may want to also set the BackgroundImageLayout to Stretch.

```
Me.button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Gradient
Me.button1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch
```

Hope that helps.